# get MAX date using limit and offset

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to use limit offset and get the most recent (MAX) date from that group

My table: column_id, column_data, column_date

I've tried

```
SELECT max(column_date) FROM table_name limit 2000 offset 22000
```

I'm trying to get the most recent date in the 2000 rows returned using the offset. In other words, I'm looking for the last date modified in each group of 2000.

Comment: @Akina, If I can answer any questions that may clear up confusion let me know.

Comment: You use MAX() without GROUP BY. In such case all data array is trteated as one group, and you obtain one output row (or none when the table is empty). `offset 22000` for single row is strange, is it?

Comment: Provide your table as CREATE TABLE script, provide some sample data (10-12 rows) as INSERT INTO script (or create online fiddle and provide the link to it). Assume that the limit is not 2000 but, for example, 3, and show desired output for this sample data with the explanations. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina, I'm not sure why the offset would considered strange. The table data is dates in datetime format. I'm not sure how to achieve what you are asking or why version would be relevant to my query here.

Comment: *I'm not sure why the offset would considered strange.* If you have **only one row** then 22000th row **not exists**.

Comment: @Akina, ahhh. I see. The table structure above has 100,000 rows. each query gets 2000 rows and I would like to retrieve the most recent date from the 2000 rows (using offset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The table structure above has 100,000 rows. each query gets 2000 rows and I would like to retrieve the most recent date from the 2000 rows (using offset).

You must extract the whole group then find MAX() over it:

```
SELECT MAX(date_column)
FROM ( SELECT date_column
       FROM source_table
       ORDER BY some_expression /* compulsory! must provide rows uniqueness! */
       LIMIT @rows_in_group OFFSET @group_offset ) AS subquery
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, Akina.